# DES - Weakness in Sbox

Tags: des, chosen-plaintext-attack, s-boxes

In the book "Introduction to Cryptography with Coding Theory ", in the chapter about the **Differential Cryptanalysis for Four Rounds** for DES algorithm, the authors say:

> There is a weakness in the box $s_{1}$. If we look at the 16 input
>   pairs with XOR equal to 0011, we discover that 12 of them have output
>   XOR equal to
>   011. Of course, we expect on the average that two pairs should yield a given output XOR, so the present case is rather extreme. A little
>   variation is to be expected; we’ll see that this large variation makes
>   it easy to find the key. There is a similar weakness in $s_{1}$,
>   though not quite as extreme. Among the 16 input pairs with XOR equal
>   to 1100, there are 8 with output XOR equal to 010.

I've understood the attack in case of a 3-round scenario.
However, it's not clear to me how this particular weakness of sboxes is used in order to attack the DES algorithm in a 4-rounds scenario.
Can you explain to me ?

ps: you find the book writing on google "Introduction to Cryptography with Coding Theory pdf" and taking the first link. The related chapter is 4.3

Comment: are you satisfied with my answer?

Answer (score 1):

The attack on 3 rounds is deterministic. It is extended to 4 rounds in a probabilistic manner, which is the normal way of carrying out differential cryptanalysis, see for example Heys' *tutorial on linear and differential cryptanalysis* which is easy to find online and uses a simple toy cipher to explain these concepts.

Basically, given enough input output pairs, one can use the fact that those differences will statistically dominate. Scan through a set of subkey bit patterns and declare the subkey bit pattern which leads to the most biased output difference distribution as the correct key bit pattern.